# Install only those R packages not already installed (inc. cran and github): any built-in way?

Tags: r, installation, package

I'm looking to simplify my code-base, and have the solution below to installing packages not already installed, but thought I'd double-check that I haven't reinvented the wheel by asking if there is some official way to do the same thing that I've somehow missed. Thanks!

```r
#' Installs any packages not already installed
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' install_if_missing(c('tidyverse','github.com/stan-dev/cmdstanr'))
#' }
install_if_missing = function(pkgs){
    missing_pkgs = NULL
    
    for(this_pkg in pkgs){
        path = NULL
        try(
            path <- find.package(basename(this_pkg),quiet=T,verbose=F)
            , silent = T
        )
        if(length(path)==0){
            missing_pkgs = c(missing_pkgs,this_pkg)
        }else{
            message('Found ',this_pkg,' @ "',path,'"')
        }
    }
    cran_missing = missing_pkgs[!grepl('github.com/',fixed=T,missing_pkgs)]
    if(length(cran_missing)>0){
        message('The following required but uninstalled CRAN packages will now be installed:\n',paste(cran_missing,collapse='\n'))
        install.packages(cran_missing)
    }
    github_missing = missing_pkgs[grepl('github.com/',fixed=T,missing_pkgs)]
    github_missing = gsub('github.com/','',github_missing)
    if(length(github_missing)>0){
        message('The following required but uninstalled Github packages will now be installed:\n',paste(this_pkg,collapse='\n'))
        remotes::install_github(github_missing)
    }
    invisible()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any base function to do what you want, so you'll need to write your own.  Some comments on the one in the question:

The help page `?installed.packages` says

> do not use it to find out if a named package is installed (use
> find.package or system.file)

because it will be slow if you have a lot of packages installed.

It also won't detect cases where a package can be updated; in some cases, having an old version of package A will prevent you from installing package B.

Your test `grep('github',missing_pkgs)` will give bad results for CRAN packages `githubinstall` and `archivist.github` (and any future packages containing "github" in their name).  You might want to test for something else.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the function to reflect your suggestions.